# Mobile version and URL Rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, mobile

I had created a dedicated mobile version for my website, not responsive theme.

I used a `wp_is_mobile` function to change some styles and script, also a template. All working good but I want to add a mobile prefix to all links like:

- `mysite.com/mobile/category/mycategory`
- `mysite.com/mobile/mypost`
- `mysite.com/mobile/tag/mobile`

etc.

Can you help with my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the options `siteurl` and `home`.

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'maybe_mobile_url');
function maybe_mobile_url() {
  if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
    add_filter('option_siteurl', 'add_mobile_url' );
    add_filter('option_home', 'add_mobile_url' );
  }
}
function add_mobile_url ($url) { return $url . '/mobile'; }
```

But, I think, that if you define `WP_SITEURL` and/or `WP_HOME` in `config.php` it will fail, and you will have to add filter to all the function that retrieve permalinks.

Comment: Actually you can just define those two constants in the `wp-config.php`. The problem is that you do not have the function `wp_is_mobile()` available, so you may have to define those two later, or write your owwn mobile switch. using the constatnts brings you the advantage of not having to filter every url-function.